# The end of my for loop is not running in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am trying to recreate the indexOf function in JavaScript. I can not get the return -1 portion to work, but the other parts work fine. It seems like the end of my for loop is not running, as I try to print out "end of loop". I have some test code as well and the outputs below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Array.prototype.myIndexOf = function(...args) {
    if(args[1] === undefined){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            if(this[i] === args[0]){
                return i;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(let i = args[1]; i < this.length; i++){
            if(this[i] === args[0]){
                return i;
            }
        }
        console.log("end of loop")
        return -1;
    }
};

// TEST

const beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison'));
console.log(beasts.myIndexOf('bison'));
// expected output: 1

// start from index 2
console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 2));
console.log(beasts.myIndexOf('bison', 2));
// expected output: 4

console.log(beasts.indexOf('giraffe'));
console.log(beasts.myIndexOf('giraffe'));
// expected output: -1
```

```
1
1
4
4
-1
undefined
```

Comment: While a bunch of people already handed you the answer, I'd encourage you to try to figure it out yourself. Step through the code in a debugger, or "play computer" with pencil and paper: walk through the code in your head and figure out what's actually happening. The indentation alone is enough to point you in the right direction: what happens in the first condition? What happens when the `for` loop ends? Where does control go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. Move the `return -1;` statement outside of the `if/else` blocks. As it's currently written, you'll only receive the -1 if it doesn't find a match ***and*** you passed in two arguments.

```js
Array.prototype.myIndexOf = function(...args) {
    if(args[1] === undefined){
        for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            if(this[i] === args[0]){
                return i;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(let i = args[1]; i < this.length; i++){
            if(this[i] === args[0]){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
};

// TEST

const beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison'));
console.log(beasts.myIndexOf('bison'));
// expected output: 1

// start from index 2
console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 2));
console.log(beasts.myIndexOf('bison', 2));
// expected output: 4

console.log(beasts.indexOf('giraffe'));
console.log(beasts.myIndexOf('giraffe'));
// expected output: -1
```

With this change, you will always hit `return -1;` if there is no match regardless of the number of parameters passed in.

Answer (score 0):

In the last test case you are not sending a second argument to the function, so it is the first part of the if-else that will run - the `if` part. There is no `return -1` in that part.